# SQL Trigger: row to be modified was already modified

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

I have a table that has items with order fields that I use to paint them on a tree.

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    menuId INTEGER,
    itemId INTEGER,
    name VARCHAR, 
    order1 INTEGER,
    order2 INTEGER,
    order3 INTEGER,
    order4 INTEGER,
);
```

Primary key is 'menuId' and 'itemId'.

Foreign key of 'menuId' with table 'menus'.

For each menu, I have an unique check so for example for menu1 I can't have two items with the same combination orders, but menu2 can.

I want to create a trigger that fires when I insert or update an item, so if add a new item with order 2, the one with order 2 updates to 3, the order 3 to 4 and so on. For now I don't care if there is blank spaces between orders, that's something that I'll try to fix on another moment.

The trigger is this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_items_menu_bibu
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON items
  FOR EACH ROW
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_menu_order();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_menu_order()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS (SELECT name
                FROM items
                WHERE order1 = NEW.order1
                AND order2 = NEW.order2
                AND order3 = NEW.order3
                AND order4 = NEW.order4
                AND menuId = NEW.menuId
                AND itemId <> NEW.itemId) THEN
        -- If exists an item for that menu with the same orders
        IF (NEW.order4 <> 0) THEN
            -- If it's an item in the sublevel4
            UPDATE items SET order4 = order4 + 1
                WHERE order1 = NEW.order1
                AND order2 = NEW.order2
                AND order3 = NEW.order3
                AND order4 = NEW.order4
                AND menuId = NEW.menuId
                AND itemId <> NEW.itemId;
        ELSEIF (NEW.order3 <> 0) THEN
            -- If it's an item in the sublevel3
            UPDATE items SET order3 = order3 + 1
                WHERE order1 = NEW.order1
                AND order2 = NEW.order2
                AND order3 = NEW.order3
                AND order4 = 0
                AND menuId = NEW.menuId
                AND itemId <> NEW.itemId;
        ELSEIF (NEW.order2 <> 0) THEN
            -- If it's an item in the sublevel2
            UPDATE items SET order2 = order2 + 1
                WHERE order1 = NEW.order1
                AND order2 = NEW.order2
                AND order3 = 0
                AND order4 = 0
                AND menuId = NEW.menuId
                AND itemId <> NEW.itemId;
        ELSE
            -- If it's an item in the sublevel1
            UPDATE items SET order1 = order1 + 1
                WHERE order1 = NEW.order1
                AND order2 = 0
                AND order3 = 0
                AND order4 = 0
                AND menuId = NEW.menuId
                AND itemId <> NEW.itemId;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If I have this items:

```
menuId  itemId  name    order1  order2  order3  order4
1       1       menu1   1       0       0       0
1       2       menu2   1       1       0       0
1       3       menu3   1       2       0       0
```

And I try to insert the following:

```
menuId  itemId  name    order1  order2  order3  order4
1       4       menu4   1       1       0       0
```

The trigger updates correctly to this:

```
menuId  itemId  name    order1  order2  order3  order4
1       1       menu1   1       0       0       0
1       4       menu4   1       1       0       0       
1       2       menu2   1       2       0       0
1       3       menu3   1       3       0       0
```

But if instead I tried to update:

```
1       3       menu3   1       1       0       0
```

I get an error saying that one row to be modified was already modified.

I understand that the problem is that the trigger made menu2 update order2 to 3, who forced menu3 to update order2 to 4, but menu3 was already modified by the original update.

What I don't know is how can I solve this or if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use `double precision` rather than `integer` for the order.

This way, you can always insert a new item between two existing items, simply by using the mean value of their orders.

The big advantage is that none of the existing entries have to be modified, so you don't need the trigger at all.

This will work just fine with an `ORDER BY`; if for any reason you need to display an integral order, generate it in the query by using the `dense_rank` window function.